# Modeling repeated measure effect with linear mixed effect models (lmer) in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

this is the first time I'm posting a question here, I hope someone will read it soon :)

I have the following problem: 
I have **three groups** of people (ADHD patients, ADHD patients under medication, and healthy patients) and **two types of treatments** (sport intervention and a placebo intervention). I have **two time-points (pre-intervention and post-intervention)**. I have several outcome variables, measuring ADHD symptoms (cognitive abilities). What I want to see is if 
- the sport intervention is followed by a larger (if any) improvement than the placebo
- the effect differs across groups.

Hence, I have to include a group*treatment interaction to the model. Some of my outcome variables are count variables, but for now, I want to focus only on the continuous ones. I was thinking about modeling the within-subject design with individual level random effects. I have two questions:

1. Do I include time (0/1 = pre/post-treatment) to the model as a fixed factor (dummy) variable?
2. Do I model random slopes as well for each individual? (does it make sense for two time points?)

So the possible model specifications:

a) lmer(y ~ group * treatment + (1|Subject), data)

b) lmer(y ~ group * treatment * time + (1|Subject), data)

c) lmer(y ~ group * treatment + (time|Subject), data)

d) lmer(y ~ group * treatment * time + (time|Subject), data)

My additional question:

3. Do I have to deal with nestedness in this model? Because each person is nested within one group (healthy/medicated/non-medicated) and also within one treatment type (sport/placebo).

Thank you in advance for your help, looking forward to your answer :)

Have a wonderful day,

Daniel

Comment: What are your research questions for this study for your continuous y variable? For example, are you interested in comparing the mean value of y between your treatment groups at each of your two time points? Or are you interested in comparing the change in the mean value of y from pre to post among treatment groups? More clarifications are needed.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If your question is about R code, it is off topic. To me, it looks like a statistics question, so I am not going to vote to close it, but you might want to clarify that you know the R part, but want help on the model.

Comment: Hi Isabella, thank you for your quick reply. My research question is whether after the sport intervention the performance improves more than after the placebo intervention or not.
I ran an lmer with individual level interepts as random effects. Afterward, I created time contrasts (from before to after the intervention) with _emmeans_ for each group-treatment pair. Finally, I checked whether the confidence intervals for the sport vs the placebo intervention overlap each other (for all 3 groups). Is it a correct approach?
I hope now it is clearer. Thanks again,

Daniel

Thank you again,